# How to display plain HTML of Web Content with Freemarker in LiferayPortal

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

In Liferay Portal 7.2, I have a Dynamic Data List of elements that are Basic Web Contents.
For each Web Content in this list I want to display a custom HTML template defined in the web content itself.

I have tried

```
<#assign records = ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>
<#if records?has_content>
    <#list records as cur_record>
        ${ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.renderRecordFieldValue
                    (cur_record.getDDMFormFieldValues("WebContent")?first, locale)}
    </#list>
</#if>
```

but it only displays the name of the WebContents.

The code I expect is something like this

```
<#assign records = ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>
<#if records?has_content>
    <#list records as cur_record>
        ${cur_record.getTemplateHTML()}
    </#list>
</#if>
```

where `getTemplateHTML()` is the method that returns the plain HTML of the Web Content.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Edit:

The Data List is a list of Basic_Web_Content Data Definition.

This is the Data List --> [Data_List_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piwte.png)

and this is the Basic_Web_Content definition --> [Data_Definition_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr9hg.png)

Edit 2.:
I also tried to print each field of all WebContents and not just the first field (using ?first) with this code

```
<#assign records = ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>
<#if records?has_content>
    <#list records as cur_record>
        <#if cur_record.getDDMFormFieldValues("WebContent")?has_content>
            <#list cur_record.getDDMFormFieldValues("WebContent") as cur_field>
                <#if cur_field?has_content>
                    ${ddlDisplayTemplateHelper.renderRecordFieldValue(cur_field, locale)}<br>
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

But again, this lists only the names of the Web Contents.
It seems that an attribute of type Web Content saves only its name..

Comment: Before we proceed, just to understand, are you trying to do with DDL the same as a structure-temple do?

Comment: Exactly. I have a DDL of WebContents with their own structures and template. I am trying to put the freemarker code inside the template definition of the DDL.

Comment: Why `cur_record.getDDMFormFieldValues("WebContent")` would return something different instead the name? How do you define this field?

Comment: @DanieleBaggio the Data Definition contains just one Web Content, an attribute for Data Definition provided by Liferay. I added 2 photos of the Data List and Data Definition details

Comment: @AlessandroCerioni, cur_record.getDDMFormFieldValues("WebContent") returns an array of values. You print the ?first only. 
Try to print out the whole array to find web content id or others useful fields..

Comment: @DanieleBaggio I tried that but it displays only the names again, like if it is the only field Liferay saves inside an attribute of type Web Content